# Laravel: validate format when at least one of two input fields required

Tags: laravel

Suppose, in the feedback form we want to ask *at least* one of two contacts: email and/or telephone number. So, in the validation rules will be `required_without` for each other:

```
$this->validate($request, [

    'email' => 'required_without:tel|email',
    'tel' => 'required_without:email|regex:/(01)[0-9]{9}/'

], $messages);
```

We need to validate the contact data format only when it has been inputted, but in the code above the format of both fields will be checked. Because we need at least one contact, `sometimes` rule is no use.

Comment: You can use required_without_all in both input

Comment: @Chintan7027, Do you mean `required_without_all:tel,email`?

Comment: 'tel':'required_without:email'

Comment: In the code in the question field I wrote so, wasn't I? 'email' => 'required_without:tel, 'tel' => 'required_without:email